# At what age should girls avoid contact with men?

Tags: halal-haram

I live in the USA and I am not Muslim.

Yesterday, my 11-year-old daughter introduced me to some of the new students at her school. They were all 11 years old, both boys and girls.  I shook hands with everyone, as is customary here.

I realized afterwards that one of the the girls was wearing a hijab. She is the only Muslim at the small school. She is open about her faith and has been happy to explain things to her friends. She didn't hesitate to shake my hand.

Did I put her in a bad position where she felt she had to shake my hand even though she shouldn't have?  Or was it OK because she is so young?

Comment: When they reach puberty

Answer (score -1):

In islam, the age at which girl should stop intermixing with boys is till puberty. But as these days situation is too much worse, that even young boys know almost everything about female private issues, so they can create issues for young girls, who have not reached puberty. Hence, its better that dont let even young girls (even 5-6 year+) to freely communicate or intermix with males or stranger males.

For detailed answer, you can contact this fatwa: https://islamqa.info/en/127946